# While creating a docker container shall i prefer defining installations in Dockerfile or shall I add a script that is called from DockerFile?

Tags: docker

While checking some of the docker files on git hub and on a local development environment, I have seen people writing some install.sh scrips and calling these in Dockerfile via:

```
COPY .../install.sh .../install.sh

RUN chmod +x .../install.sh

RUN .../install.sh
```

I am not comfortable with this usage but as I have seen it in a few locations may be it is acceptable?

What is the best practice?

Best Regards

Comment: I feel like most of the standard Docker images I've seen embed most of their installation logic directly in the Dockerfile, but there also isn't very much of it.  If embedding a shell script makes your logic clearer or more testable then there's nothing wrong with doing that.  I wouldn't say it's either encouraged or discouraged.

Comment: I think if you have a complex shell script it's a lot cleaner and more manageable to put it into a file and `COPY` that into the image rather than trying to embed a long, multiline shell script in a `RUN` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker provide a caching system to make builds faster.
When you build a Docker image, for each step, it will create a container, run the command, stop it, and cache it.

For example:

```
RUN echo 'Hello world!' # STEP 1
RUN echo 'Bip boup'     # STEP 2
RUN apt-get update -y   # STEP 3
RUN echo 'ZAP!'         # STEP 4
```

The first time you build this image, it will take some time because of the STEP 3 (`apt-get update`).

But the second time, it will use the cached containers used to run the steps and will not run again `apt-get update`.

If you edit a step before the `apt-get update -y`:

```
RUN echo 'Hello world!' # STEP 1
RUN echo 'Bip bip boup' # STEP 2 (edited)
RUN apt-get update -y   # STEP 3
RUN echo 'ZAP!'         # STEP 4
```

You will see that the build will not use cached containers for the edited step and the following.

---

**In conclusion, if you use an external script, Docker will not be aware if you made changes in it and will continue to use the cached container (and will not `COPY`).**

> To avoid using intermediate containers, you can use `docker build --force-rm` or `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate`

---

#### Entrypoint

Usually you will see something like this:

```
COPY myscript.sh /
RUN chmod +x /mysqcript.sh

ENTRYPOINT '/myscript.sh'
```

For this part, you can find informations about ENTRYPOINT on this page: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

To resume, the script will be executed after the container started and you will be able for example to use and interact with mounted volumes. (Which is not possible directly in the image).

It is really useful for local environment when you want to use a mounted volume for your project to avoid rebuild your image every time you make changes and still want to run commands such as `composer install`, `ng serve`, `webpack --watch`, etc.

Comment: so there is no rule for bast practice, both methods are fine as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: The best practice is to not use an external script, or you will not get the benefit of docker caching